# Finding optimal weight factor for SOR

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods

I am using the SOR method and need to find the optimal weight factor. I think a good way to go about this is to run my SOR code with a number of omegas from 0 to 2, then store the number of iterations for each of these. Then I can see which iteration is the lowest and which omega it corresponds to. Being a novice programer, however, I am unsure how to go about this.

Here is my SOR code:

```
function [x, l] = SORtest(A, b, x0, TOL,w)
[m n] = size(A);                            % assigning m and n to number of rows and columns of A
l = 0;                                      % counter variable
x = [0;0;0];                                % introducing solution matrix
max_iter = 200;
    while (l < max_iter)                        % loop until max # of iters.
        l = l + 1;                              % increasing counter variable
        for i=1:m                               % looping through rows of A
            sum1 = 0; sum2 = 0;                 % intoducing sum1 and sum2
            for j=1:i-1                         % looping through columns
                sum1 = sum1 + A(i,j)*x(j);      % computing sum using x
            end
            for j=i+1:n
                sum2 = sum2 + A(i,j)*x0(j);     % computing sum using more recent values in x0
            end
            x(i) =(1-w)*x0(i) + w*(-sum1-sum2+b(i))/A(i,i);   % assigning elements to the solution matrix.
        end
        if abs(norm(x) - norm(x0)) < TOL        % checking tolerance
            break
        end
        x0 = x;                                 % assigning x to x0 before relooping
    end

end
```

Comment: How would you run your code if omega was 1? If you can answer that, then think about how you can use a for loop to incrementally change onega and re-run your function.

Comment: If omega was one it would simply be the gauss seidel method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do.  Simply loop through values of `w` and determine what the total number of iterations is at each `w`.  Once the function finishes, check to see if this is the current minimum number of iterations required to get a solution.  If it is, then update what the final solution would be.  Once we iterate over all `w`, the result would be the solution vector that produced the smallest number of iterations to converge.  Bear in mind that SOR has the `w` such that it does **not** include `w = 0` or `w = 2`, or `0 < w < 2`, so we can't include 0 or 2 in the range.  As such, do something like this:

```
omega_vec = 0.01:0.01:1.99;
final_x = x0;
min_iter = intmax;

for w = omega_vec
    [x, iter] = SORtest(A, b, x0, TOL, w);
    if iter < min_iter
        min_iter = iter;
        final_x = x;
    end
end
```

The loop checks to see if the total number of iterations at each `w` is less than the current minimum.  If it is, log this and also record what the solution vector was.  The final solution vector that was the minimum over all `w` will be stored in `final_x`.

Comment: When I try this code it doesn't run properly. It says "busy" until I terminate it.

Comment: @user3681755 - Yup... that's because you probably provided an omega where the solution doesn't converge.  The standard practice is to **cap** the total number of iterations.  If it goes beyond this you stop. Make this  your `while` loop: `while(l <= 200)`, where 200 is the number of maximum iterations you want to use.

Comment: @user3681755 - BTW, there is a mistake in your code.  You want to return **`l`**, **not `i`**.  You also want `l` to start at `0`.  I've edited your code to reflect this.  Please review it.